# Linux configuration files names with numbers

Tags: linux, configuration, rsyslog

I just wonder why some tools have default configuration files with numbers in their names.

For example: `50-default.conf` (for rsyslog).

What's the reason for this number and what does it mean ?

Comment: My rsyslog doesn't have that. Can you update your question to say what  Linux distribution you're on? However, the number could be an indication of order in which f.ex. config files are read.

Comment: This is a docker container based on the following image : https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker (Ubuntu). The reading order indication makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These numbers are for config file ordering and precedence. I.e. if the same parameter configuration is present in `10-smth.conf` and `20-smth.conf` the latter will overwrite first one.